# Groovy string comparison in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to compare two strings in Jenkins pipeline. The code more or less look like this:

```
script {

def str1 = 'test1.domainname-test.com'
def str2 = 'test1.domainname-test.com'

if ( str1 == str2 ) {
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORT'
    error("TENANT_NAME $TENANT_NAME.domainname-test.com is already  defined in domainname-test.com record set. Please specify unique name. Exiting...")
}

}
```

str1 is fed by a preceeding command I skipped here due to simplicity. I am getting this error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String domainname
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried equals method too, same result. As if it stucked on those dots, thinking it's some kind of property. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing curly brackets surrounding the `TENANT_NAME` variable name. In your example:

```
error("TENANT_NAME $TENANT_NAME.domainname-test.com is already  defined in domainname-test.com record set. Please specify unique name. Exiting...")
```

the `$` sign gets applied to `TENANT_NAME.domainname`. And because `TENANT_NAME` is a string, Groovy interprets the following part as you were trying to access `domainname` property from a String class, and you get **No such field found: field java.lang.String domainname** exception.

To avoid such problems, wrap your variable name with `{}` and you will be fine.

```
error("TENANT_NAME ${TENANT_NAME}.domainname-test.com is already  defined in domainname-test.com record set. Please specify unique name. Exiting...")
```

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming that the problem lies within if condition check and spend some time digging in a wrong place. Lesson learned - never write the code when you're tired :) as this makes debugging harder.